PySpark streaming connect with AWS Kinesis Datastream
I am trying to read an AWS Kinesis Data Stream into a PySpark sql dataframe.
this is my python code
import pyspark as ps

spark = (
    ps.sql.SparkSession.builder
    .config(map= {
        'spark.jars': r'./streaming-app-poc/src/spark-streaming-sql-kinesis-connector_2.12-1.0.0.jar'
    })
    .getOrCreate()
)

(
    spark
    .readStream
    .format('aws-kinesis')
    .options(**{
        'kinesis.region'          : 'us-east-2',
        'kinesis.streamName'      : 'sensor-data-stream',
        'kinesis.consumerType'    : 'GetRecords',
        'kinesis.endpointUrl'     : 'https://kinesis.us-east-2.amazonaws.com',
        'kinesis.startingposition': 'LATEST'
    })
    .load()
)

and I'm getting the following error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[15], line 12
      1 (
      2     spark
      3     .readStream
      4     .format('aws-kinesis')
      5     .options(**{
      6         'kinesis.region'          : 'us-east-2',
      7         'kinesis.streamName'      : 'sensor-data-stream',
      8         'kinesis.consumerType'    : 'GetRecords',
      9         'kinesis.endpointUrl'     : 'https://kinesis.us-east-2.amazonaws.com',
     10         'kinesis.startingposition': 'LATEST'
     11     })
---> 12     .load()
     13 )

File c:\Users\hdahmed\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\pyspark\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\streaming\readwriter.py:304, in DataStreamReader.load(self, path, format, schema, **options)
    302     return self._df(self._jreader.load(path))
    303 else:
--> 304     return self._df(self._jreader.load())

File c:\Users\hdahmed\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\pyspark\Lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1317     self.command_header +\
   1318     args_command +\
   1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322 return_value = get_return_value(
   1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1325 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File c:\Users\hdahmed\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\pyspark\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py:179, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    177 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    178     try:
--> 179         return f(*a, **kw)
    180     except Py4JJavaError as e:
    181         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File c:\Users\hdahmed\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\pyspark\Lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o92.load.
: org.apache.spark.SparkClassNotFoundException: [DATA_SOURCE_NOT_FOUND] Failed to find the data source: aws-kinesis. Please find packages at `https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html`.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.dataSourceNotFoundError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:725)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:647)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.loadInternal(DataStreamReader.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:145)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: aws-kinesis.DefaultSource
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:592)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$5(DataSource.scala:633)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$4(DataSource.scala:633)
    at scala.util.Failure.orElse(Try.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:633)
    ... 12 more

I have installed PySpark using pip install pyspark and installed the spark-kinesis connector jar file from https://github.com/awslabs/spark-sql-kinesis-connector
I am new to spark and PySpark, from what I understand, spark is unable to locate the classes in the jar file.
I would like to know where I'm making a mistake or there's something wrong in my implementation
Also if someone could share documentation for spark-kinesis connector, that would be greatly appreciated
